# Redux actions are not mapped to react props

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm making my first react-native app and I cant seem to bind my actions to props. In the component `this.props.actions` is an empty, and `LoginActions` is also an empty object in the `mapDispatchToProps` function.  This leads me to believe its an issue in the action or the connect binding.  Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import {
  View,
  StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';
import {
  google,
  facebook,
  twitter,
} from 'react-native-simple-auth';
import LoginConstants from '../../constants/Login.constants';
import * as LoginActions from '../../actions/Login.actions';
import LoginForm from '../../components/LoginForm';

class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    alert(JSON.stringify(this.props.actions))
    this.loginActions = {
      google,
      facebook,
      twitter,
    };

    this.loginAction = this.loginAction.bind(this);
  }

  loginAction(platform) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(this.props.actions))
    // this.loginActions[platform](LoginConstants[platform])
    //   .then((info) => {
    //     alert(info);
    //     // info.user - user details from the provider
    //     // info.credentials - tokens from the provider
    //   }).catch((error) => {
    //     throw Error(`Error ${error.code}: ${error.description}`);
    //   });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <LoginForm actions={this.loginActions} loginAction={this.loginAction} />
    );
  }
}

Login.propTypes = {
  actions: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  user: PropTypes.object
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
});

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    user: state.user
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(LoginActions, dispatch)
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);
```

Actions:

```
import LoginConstants from '../constants/Login.constants';

export function getUser(userId) {
  return {
    type: LoginConstants.actions.getUser,
    payload: new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve({
          userId: '123ddgs',
        });
      }, 2000);
    });
  };
};

export function saveUser(user) {
  return {
    type: LoginConstants.actions.saveUser,
    payload: new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve({
          userId: '123ddgs',
        });
      }, 2000);
    })
  };
};
```

Reducer:

```
import LoginConstants from '../constants/Login.constants';

const loginReducers = (state = {
  user: {},
  prevStates: []
}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LoginConstants.actions.getUser:
      state = {
        ...state,
        user: action.payload,
        prevStates: [...state.prevStates, action.payload]
      };
      break;

    case LoginConstants.actions.saveUser:
      state = {
        ...state,
        user: action.payload,
        prevStates: [...state.prevStates, action.payload]
      };
      break;
  }

  return state;
};

export default loginReducers;
```

Store:

```
import {
  createStore,
  combineReducers,
  applyMiddleware,
} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import promise from 'redux-promise-middleware';
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';
import loginReducers from './src/reducers/Login.reducers';
import beerReducers from './src/reducers/Beer.reducers';

export default createStore(
  combineReducers({
    loginReducers,
    beerReducers,
  }),
  {},
  applyMiddleware(createLogger(), thunk, promise())
);
```

Comment: If `LoginActions` is an empty object in your `mapDispatchToProps`, maybe you're not correctly exporting/importing the functions.

Comment: @kngroo well i have attached the actions file there as well as the store.  I cannot see how it is improperly exported, although I did think that myself initially

Comment: That is strange. If LoginActions is an empty object, it means that the functions were not imported. Are you sure that this path `'../../actions/Login.actions'` is correct? Is there a directory called `Login.actions` in there?

Comment: @kngroo its a js file, but I don't need the extension as i understand.  Its certainly there.  I get intelisense infor

Comment: What happens when you tty importing the actions separately? `import {getUser, saveUser} from '../../actions/Login.actions'`

Comment: @yahyazini I still get undefined in `mapDispatchToProps` for `getUser` and `dispatch`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON.stringify strips functions from its output and therefore, the actions and dispatcher were not visible in the alert output.